# Can't commit file changes using CVS and WinSCP

Tags: linux, cvs, winscp

I'm using CVS and WinSCP to add a new cgi file to a directory /var/www/cgi-files. After editing and saving the file I go to commit it on WinSCP in the terminal with the command

```
cvs commit -m "fails" new_fails.cgi
```

but get the error

```
Command 'cvs commit -m "fails" new_fails.cgi' failed with
return code 1 and error message 
cvs commit: nothing known about 'new_fails.cgi'
cvs[commit aborted]:correct above errors first!.
```

Both the current directory and the directory the file is in is:

```
 /var/www/cgi-files
```

The permissions octal is set to 0775 (rwxrwxr-x).

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Is it really failing in WinSCP console window only? Or does it fail, even if you run it in shell?

Comment: It fails from both, I have no problems making changes to other files in the same directory using the same command. ie 'cvs commit -m "different file" different_file.cgi

Comment: So please update the question accordingly (removing all references to WinSCP). It's confusing otherwise.

Comment: Did you do a `cvs add new_fails.cgi`?